# Given $A$-modules $N \subset M$ such that $N_m=M_m$ for all maximal ideals $m$, show that $M=N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am working on this [exam question 6](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/documents/graduate/prelims/algebra/alg-11.pdf)

> $A$ is commutative ring with $1$
>
> a) If $N \subset M$ are $A$-modules and $N_m=M_m$ for all maximal ideals $m$, show that $M=N$.

We know that $N_m=M_m$ and thus $M_m/N_m=0$ for all maximal ideals $m$. Also $M_m/N_m \cong (M/N)_m=0$ for all maximal ideals $m$ since being zero is equivalent to all localizations at maximal ideals being zero we know that $M/N=0$ and therefore $M=N$. Is this correct so far?

> b) Suppose that $A$ has only finitly many maximal ideals. If $A_m$ is noetherian for all maximal ideals $m$, show that $A$ is noetherian.

Unfortunatly I have no idea here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a)$ is correct. $b)$ is a consequence of $a)$, here is a little sketch:

Given an ascending chain of ideals of $A$, for each maximal ideal the localized chain stabilizes at some point by assumption. Since there are only finitely many maximal ideals, we find one single index, where all localized chains stabilize uniformly. By $a)$ the chain of ideals in $A$ stabilizes at this point.

Comment: great thanks. I have one clarifying question. Let $I_1 \subset I_2 \subset ...$ an ascending chain and $I \nsubseteq m$ than localizing the ascending chain at $m$ just leads to a zero chain right? So this chain already stabilizes at index $n=1$?

Comment: $I_{\mathfrak m}=0$ if and only if the annihilator of $I$ is not contained in $\mathfrak m$. In particular $I_{\mathfrak m}$ will never vanish, if $A$ is a domain.

Comment: What you probably mean is the following: If $I_1$ is not cointained in $\mathfrak m$, then $(I_2/I_1)_{\mathfrak m}=0$, since it is annihiliated by $I_1$, which contains a unit in the localization. Then the chain stabilizes at $n=1$.

Comment: In particular one can sharpen the statement: Let $A$ be a commutative ring with $1$, such that any non-zero element is contained in only finitely many maximal ideals. If $A$ is notherian after localization at each maximal ideal, then $A$ is noetherian. An important use of the sharpened result is the example of a infinite-dimensional noetherian ring by Nagata.